# How to add & show new fields in posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im have created post types called `news` in `wp-admin` which will be able to add New News and display on News page.

Here are some screenshot first look at them, that is how i want to display stuff.

1. title
2. date
3. description (summary of 50 words)
4. readmore button to open the full post.
5. Download button ( beside read more button for pdf form which will be download )

[image]

Right now I have only

1. title
2. description (without summary)

[image]

Here is my `function.php` code

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'News',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'News' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),

    )
);
}
```

After adding above code in my function.php, I have only two options in my add new news in admin panel,

**How do I add a new field in admin for `date`. Date will be the date of news event.**

**How do i add a `download button`?**
Something like for example i want a field in new post, where i just upload file or attach file that will show on download button in post.

**Secondly How to add readmore button to open full post?**

**How do i create a new page for full post, when we click on read more, how will i show in new page?**

My admin view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using plugins like [simple fields](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-fields) or [custom fields](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields)

I usually do it manually, with two ways depending on the final goal:

1. Adding custom taxonomies, by register_taxonomy wordpress function
2. Adding custom metadatas, by add_meta_boxes action.

I'm trying to post you an example, but i'm not able to indent it properly...